# Android: set multiple button selection onClick

Tags: android, button, onclick

I have a set of buttons:

```
[Button1]
[Button2]
[Button3]
[Button4]
[Button5]
[Button6]
```

All of which share the same onClick method:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button b = (Button) v;
        Button comp;
        int i = b.getId();
        selected[i] = !selected[i];
        b.setSelected(selected[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                selected[j] = false;
                comp = lifestyleButtonArray.get(j);

                if(comp.isSelected())
                    comp.setSelected(selected[j]);
                    Log.w(TAG,"[Button] selection for button #"+j+"="+selected[j]);

            }
        }
    }
});
```

The first part of the onClick method works as expected. When a button is clicked, toggle the buttons 'selection' value to change the color of the button  (defined in a drawable xml file) and then de-select all other buttons, so that at most one button is marked 'selected' at a time.

The selection part works, but the buttons are not re-drawn with the appropriate color, so it appears that two buttons are selected!

I have tried invalidate and requestLayout, but that didn't help. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** After giving this some more thought, the real question to be asked here is:

How do I update a view that is not the view from the onClick method?

In my example, when I select button1 I want to be able to remove the selection from buttons 2-6, but since buttons 2-6 are not the view being called, they show the correct selected value (that they are unselected) but do not update their UI view to the 'non-selected' color!

Comment: why dont you let your Activity implements the onClickListener, and then override one method onClick(View v ) for all your Buttons, and then you can Switch between them using Switch(v.getId(){ case R.id.btn1 : //TODO....break; case R.id.btn2 : ....etc

Comment: Because this is all inside a larger activity that implements its own onClick method to take care of another portion of code. I don't need to be able to switch between the buttons though, I need to be able to set the selection value for a button and have it re-draw.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the selected state of the button, you might call the "invalidate()" function on each button to force them to update on the next cycle.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work because it is outside the scope of the View that was clicked, the invalidate calls don't update the UI.